# sum of results from for - in loop, in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, for-loop

I am playing around with Apples sample code for Health kit.  They have put a for-in loop function to iterate through all the sample within the last 24hours.  The code of course works great.

Using the for-in loop in swift, would it be possible to find the sum of all the values?

I have been trying but can not find the solution.

Thanks
Chris

Here is the code:

```
for sample in results as [HKQuantitySample] {
                let joules = sample.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.jouleUnit())
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with the Health Kit framework, but you can sum all of the values in an array using `reduce`:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let sum = array.reduce(0, +)  // sum == 15
```

`0` is the starting value, and `+` is the operation to be performed on the starting value and each item in the array.

Looking at your code, you might need to provide a closure to reduce, something like this:

```
let samples = results as [HKQuantitySample]
let sum = samples.reduce(0.0) {
    $0 + $1.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.jouleUnit())
}
```

Comment: Roman, you were correct, was a lot easier that way than trying to use the for loop.

Comment: It is safer, and it lets you define `sum` as a constant, which is also good. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `samples` is an `HKQuantitySample` array :

```
// samples is an [HKQuantitySample]
var joulesSum : Double = 0.0 // Make sure that : it's a var not a let and Double is the right type

for aSample in samples {
    joulesSum += aSample.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.jouleUnit())
}
```

Or in your case :

```
var joulesSum : Double = 0.0

for aResult in results {
    joulesSum += aResult.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.jouleUnit())
}
```

*Did it helped ? If it didn't, please add the previous code (where your `results` is created).*